# Swift app crashes on delete a row from UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I know it's a very simple and basic issue, especially for the person who works with Swift 4 years, but I stuck!

I'm trying to delete the row with:

```
let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in
        do {
            self.usersTableView.beginUpdates()
            self.viewModel.users.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            self.coreDataStack.mainContext.delete(user)
            self.usersTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            self.usersTableView.endUpdates()

            try self.coreDataStack.mainContext.save()                
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not delete the user \(user) because of the \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
```

and my

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.viewModel.users.count
}
```

I get crash on trying to tap delete button with the next error:

```
attempt to delete row 0 from section 0 which only contains 0 rows before the update
```

Can someone help me to understand how it works?

Comment: try to remove the beginupdates() and endUpdates() and then try

Comment: Could you please show me the code for the ViewModel and your 'coreDataStack'?

Comment: your error says you are trying to delete zero'th row from section 0, which does not have any cell in the section. also change the code order as : -> self.usersTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic) self.viewModel.users.remove(at: indexPath.row)
self.coreDataStack.mainContext.delete(user) self.usersTableView.endUpdates()

Comment: Are you using a `FetchedResultsController`?

Comment: @Paulw11 no, I'm fetching simply ALL users with fetchRequest

Comment: Hmm. Well the exception says that the table view thought that there were 0 rows before you removed the roe, so something is wrong in code not shown here

Answer (score 0):

The best effective way of deleting row from UITableView and UICollectionView is using performBatchUpdates (it is available for only iOS 11+)

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
       self.usersTableView.performBatchUpdates({
             self.viewModel.users.remove(at: indexPath.row)
             self.coreDataStack.mainContext.delete(user)
             self.usersTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)                      
             }, completion: { (finish) in
             self.usersTableView.reloadData()         
             }) 

       }
       else { }
```